# Neo4j doubling returned nodes if they have biderectional relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I create 2 nodes with both relationships:

```
CREATE (ee:Person { name: "Emil"})
CREATE (js:Person { name: "Johan"}),
(ee)-[:KNOWS]->(js),
(js)-[:KNOWS]->(ee)
```

then if I do

```
match u return u
```

in Rows there are will be 2 nodes

BUT if I do

```
match u--f return u,f
```

in Rows there are will be 4 nodes.

How can I return only 2 nodes if I don't mind about directions?
I just need to return all friends of the user and there are duplicate of it's friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using both relationships

To fix your query (using your data), use `DISTINCT`, as in this query:

```
MATCH (u)--(f)
RETURN DISTINCT u, f;
```

#### Using a single relationship

But you probably should not have 2 relationships (in opposite directions) in the first place. If you just create *one* of them:

```
CREATE (ee:Person { name: "Emil"})
CREATE (js:Person { name: "Johan"}),
(ee)-[:KNOWS]->(js);
```

Then your *original* query would have returned 2 rows as well.

Comment: unidirectional relationships only work when the relationship is mutual. In this case X knows Y doesn't mean Y knows X so having two relationships is structurally correct.

Comment: You are right in general, but in many (if not most) use cases "X knows Y" automatically implies "Y knows X".  The latter certainly seemed to apply for *this* question, given the existence of the two opposite-direction relationships. @SoulCub can speak up if this is an issue.